# Warning message in Ros navigation stack

Tags: ros

When I try to launch

`roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation turtlebot3_navigation.launch map_file:=$HOME/map.yaml`

`[ WARN] [1678717811.343719704]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.100446 timeout was 0.1.`

and there is error in rviz in robot model also

- [roslaunch warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So5Mt.png)
- [Rviz error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rq9.png)
- `rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CUMJ.png)

Help me solve error

`amcl.launch`

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="scan_topic"     default="scan"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">

    <param name="min_particles"             value="500"/>
    <param name="max_particles"             value="3000"/>
    <param name="kld_err"                   value="0.02"/>
    <param name="update_min_d"              value="0.20"/>
    <param name="update_min_a"              value="0.20"/>
    <param name="resample_interval"         value="1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance"       value="0.5"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a"            value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate"          value="50.0"/>

    <remap from="scan"                      to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    <param name="laser_max_range"           value="3.5"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams"           value="180"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit"               value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short"             value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max"               value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand"              value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit"           value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short"        value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type"          value="likelihood_field"/>

    <param name="odom_model_type"           value="diff"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id"             value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame_id"             value="base_footprint"/>

  </node>
</launch>
```

`turtlebot3_navigation.launch`

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/maps/map.yaml"/>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>
  <arg name="move_forward_only" default="false"/>

  <!-- Turtlebot3 -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_remote.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="$(arg model)" />
  </include>

  <!-- Map server -->
  <node pkg="map_server" name="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)"/>

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch"/>

  <!-- move_base -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/launch/move_base.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="$(arg model)" />
    <arg name="move_forward_only" value="$(arg move_forward_only)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- rviz -->
  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find turtlebot3_navigation)/rviz/turtlebot3_navigation.rviz"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. The problem appears to be with your transform tree, but it's impossible to say why without seeing your tf file.

Comment: I added amcl.launch file and rqt_tf_tree output image please help @BTables